# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no ocijdbc12 in java.library.path

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

We are trying to move away  from Oracle 10g which has the lib and lib32 folders and the jars used are ojdbc14.jar and classes12.zip folders.

I am not sure where i am missing any files. Could some one please guide me to get this database conenction issue fixed?

we are trying to move to Oracle 12 and in the oracle home path we have the ojdbc6.jar that we have to use. and in the lib folder we are suppose to have the libocijdbc12.so file which I do.

But when i try to establish the java connection i get the below error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no ocijdbc12 in java.library.path
```

Comment: Please add code so that someone can help you better.

Comment: None of the [over 5000 existing posts with this error message](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java.lang.unsatisfiedlinkerror) helped?